# Extract a number to the right of a text python

Tags: python

Lets assume I have some string in python ending with some number.

```
2te2xt12
text1
text143
te2xt341
```

How can I get the right most number sequence:

```
2te2xt12  >>  12
text1     >>  1
text143   >>  143
te2xt341  >>  341
```

Is there a simple and easy way.

I know nothing about re

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this? The function test should do what you need.

```
import re

def test(string):
    m = re.search(r'\d+$', string)
    if m is not None:
        print(m.group())
```

Comment: Thanks how can I get te2xt341 >> te2xt

Comment: @KhalilAlHooti use regex groups. in the above answer you can modify as m = re.search(r'(.*?)(\d+)$', string) and then print(m.group(1)) go get te2xt and print(m.group(2)) to get 341

Answer (score 5):

```
import re
s=r"""1231ololo767980716"""
re.match('.*?([0-9]+)$', s).group(1)

>>> '767980716'
```

or

```
next(re.finditer(r'\d+$', s)).group(0)
>>> '767980716'
```

Explanation of regexp components:

- `.*?` is a non-greedy match and consumes only as much as possible (a
  greedy match would consume everything except for the last digit).
- `[0-9]` and `\d` are two different ways of capturing digits. Note that the latter also matches digits in other writing schemes, like `୪`
  or `൨`
- Parentheses (()) make the content of the expression a group, which can be retrieved with group(1) (or 2 for the second group, 0  for the whole match).
- `+` means multiple entries (at least one number at the end).
- `$` matches only the end of the input.

and all components you can find here: https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html very helpful cheat sheet

Answer (score 3):

This code which uses regex `\d+$` should get you what you are exactly looking for,

```
import re

arr = ['2te2xt12',
'text1',
'text143',
'te2xt341']

for s in arr:
 m = re.search(r'\d+$', s)
 if (m):
  print(s + ' >> ' + m.group())
```

Prints,

```
2te2xt12 >> 12
text1 >> 1
text143 >> 143
te2xt341 >> 341
```

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

It is quite simple using regex in python

```
re.findall('\d+$',yourString)[0]
```

To know more about regular expressions refer the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=re#module-re)